# Falcon-7B llm giving random output

Tags: nlp, transformer, huggingface, gpt, llm

I am using a falcon 7B model for a chatbot without any finetuning with the following code

```
model_name = "ybelkada/falcon-7b-sharded-bf16"

bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16,
)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_name,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    trust_remote_code=True
)
model.config.use_cache = False
from transformers import pipeline

generator = pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    tokenizer="gpt2",
)

result = generator("Hi")
print(result)
```

the result isnt as expected and it outputs
[{'generated_text': 'Hi8\x10=:AHi8\x10>Hi8\x10>:AHi8\x10?'}].
How can i fix this and make it output a proper response

Comment: Does it work better without quantization?

Comment: no there is no difference without it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the GPT-2 tokenizer instead of the model's own tokenizer. Try getting the tokenizer from the model instead:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import transformers

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)
pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)
```

Comment: @SaketVempaty did my advice help make the model generate normal text?

Comment: yes it did although the falcon model probably needs to be fine tuned for giving meaningful answers